# Let $f$ differentiable on $(a, \infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$. Show that $\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

> Let $f$ differentiable on $(a, \infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$. Show that $\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|=0$. I would like to know if my proof holds, please and have a feedback.

As $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, we have by definition that: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists x_0 \ \forall x\ge x_0$: $|\frac{f(x)}{x}|<\epsilon$.

Let $k \in (a,\infty)$. We have then $\forall \epsilon>0, \ \forall x\ge x_0$:

$|\inf|f'(x)||=\inf|f'(x)|\le|f'(x)|=\Big|\lim_{x\to k}\frac{f(x)-f(k)}{x-k}\Big|\le \lim_{x\to k}\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(k)}{x-k}\Big|< \lim_{x\to k}\epsilon=\epsilon$

So $\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|=0$ as $k$ is arbitrary.

I'm not sure at all of this proof. The last inequaility seems to me false, but I didn't find a counter example. Another approach was to distinguish cases: $f$ converges or $f$ diverges (then apply L'Hôpital).

Comment: Do you mean $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \inf$?

Comment: Your $k$ doesn't move as the precision $\epsilon$ moves what is suspicious. Also you should rename some variables in order to avoid confusions, I don't see why $|f'(x)| = \left| \lim_{x \rightarrow k} \frac{f(x) - f(k)}{x-k} \right|$ so I think the $x$ at the left side is a $k$. Am I right?

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem? I'd assume that would be the best step to solve the problem.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Yes, sorry for misstype

Comment: @kingW3 Yes, I know. But, I tried to use it and didn't really get a result

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ satisfies equation 1, is differentiable and is $1$ everywhere but $0$ which clearly includes $\infty$.

Comment: Think of $f'(c)=(f(2x_0)-f(x_0))/(2x_0-x_0)=f(2x_0)/x_0-f(x_0)/x_0=2f(2x_0)/(2x_0)-f(x_0)/x_0$ You have $|f'(c)|<2\epsilon +\epsilon$

Comment: @kingW3 Thank you, I think I understood how to prove the statement. I just have a question, does the statement hold for $\limsup$?

Comment: No, take for example $f(x) =\sin x$

Comment: I have solved this before using mean value theorem. Let me know if you want me to retry!

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli If you could post your answer, I would really appreaciate it! I would like to see your idea! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Your computations/intuition are good except that you are looking at the wrong limit by sending $x \to k$. You should send $x \to \infty$ because that is where you have some assumptions available. So, let me spell that out.

Given $\epsilon >0 $ I will show that for any $y$ there is a $c$ such that $y < c$ and $|f'(c)| < \epsilon$. I leave it to you to confirm that this implies $\liminf_{x \to \infty} |f'(x)| = 0. $

Given $\epsilon>0$ and $y>a$, we know that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} - \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(y)}{x} = 0 \, .
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{x-y} = 1 \, .
$$
So, together they give
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{x-y} = 0 \, .
$$
So, there exists an $x>y$ such that
$$
\left \vert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right \vert < \epsilon \, .
$$
However, by mean value theorem we do have a $c \in (y,x)$ -- of course ultimately $x>y$ -- such that
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \, .
$$
Therefore,
$$
|f'(c)| < \epsilon \, .
$$
So, to wrap up, for any $\epsilon >0$ and any $y>a$ I found a $c$ such that $ c>y$ and $|f'(c)| < \epsilon.$ Informally, this means that there will be arbitrarily small values for $|f'(x)|$ arbitrarily late at the tail.

Comment: I think I got the idea. Could we consider a sequence $n<c_n<2n$ to prove the statement? Because  we want to check the limit of increasing sequence of $|f'|'s$ inf's. Could it work? And if yes, why couldn't we compute the same for statement with $\limsup$ instead of $\liminf$? Where the proof won't hold? (without looking for a counter-example)

Comment: Because we need an unknown large distance between y and x for the  quotient to be small. We have no control over, sys, when x=y+1. The quotient is not small for y and x larger than a cutoff. You first fix y and only then find your x which depending on y can be forced to be very large.

Comment: Specifically, you won't know if for y=n the value $x=2n$ will suffice or not.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}|f'(x)|=l>0$.
Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{y\geq x}|f'(y)|=\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}|f'(x)|>l/2$,
so there exists $x_{0}$ such that $\inf_{y\geq x}|f'(y)|>l/2$ whenever
$x>x_{0}$. In particular, $|f'(y)|>l/2$ for all $y>x_{0}$.

Fix $x_{1}=x_{0}+1$. Let $x>x_{1}$ be arbitrary. By mean-value theorem, there
exists $\xi_{x}\in(x_{1},x)$ such that $|\frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}|=|f'(\xi_{x})|>l/2$.
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}\\
 & = & \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(x_{1})}{x}}{1-\frac{x_{1}}{x}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac{f(x_{1})}{x}\rightarrow0$,
$\frac{f(x)}{x}\rightarrow0$, and $\frac{x_{1}}{x}\rightarrow0$.
Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}=0$.
This contradicts to $|\frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}|>l/2$ whenever
$x>x_{1}$.

Comment: Remark: I should separate the case that $\liminf |f'(x)| = \infty$ and $\liminf |f'(x)|<\infty$. For the case $\liminf |f'(x)| = \infty$, I leave it as an exercise.

Comment: I don't see the need for proof by contradiction.  The straightforward version of the argument would go: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, for every $N > a$, $\frac{f(x) - f(N)}{x - N} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, so there exists $y > N$ such that $|f'(y)| < \varepsilon$, implying that $\liminf_{x\to \infty} |f'(x)| \le \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: Yes. However, both your direct proof and my indirect proof are valid.